# less mixin or selector to change position based on sibling index?

Tags: html, css, less

I'm trying to adjust the position of several sibling divs based on which sibling they are. Currently, they're all `position: absolute`, but that's not set in stone.

They are each a few hundred pixels tall, but I want them to overlap each other so that the ones behind only 'peek' out above the ones in front by a few pixels. The easiest way I can think of to do this would be a Less mixin for `nth-of-type` that, instead of only applying the rules to the matching one index, instead passes the index into the mixin. Basically, I want this:

```
&:nth-of-type(@n) {
    top: @n * 20px;
}
```

**Edit:** what I'm currently doing:

```
&:nth-of-type(1) {
    .card_offset(1);
}
&:nth-of-type(2) {
    .card_offset(2);
}
&:nth-of-type(3) {
    .card_offset(3);
}
&:nth-of-type(4) {
    .card_offset(4);
}
```

Obviously this is nonoptimal. Is there a better way to do this in Less?

Alternatively, is there a CSS field for something like `'layout-height'` that would give the div a certain height (not its full height) in the layout?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you know the number of elements in advance (or are recalculating your css on the fly somehow), then essentially what you have works if [put into a loop structure](http://blog.thehippo.de/2012/04/programming/do-a-loop-with-less-css/) which I originally discovered [here on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226347/can-you-do-a-javascript-for-loop-inside-of-less-css).

**LESS Code**

```
.loop(@index) when (@index > 0) {
     //set top amount
    &:nth-of-type(@{index}) { //NOTE: 1.3.3 and under is just @index, not @{index}
        top: @index * 20px;
    }

     // next iteration
     .loop(@index - 1);
}

// end the loop when index is 0
.loop(0) {}

.yourElem {
    @n: 6; //num of elements (could skip this and just put number in)
    .loop(@n);
}
```

**Outputs**

```
.yourElem:nth-of-type(6) {
  top: 120px;
}
.yourElem:nth-of-type(5) {
  top: 100px;
}
.yourElem:nth-of-type(4) {
  top: 80px;
}
.yourElem:nth-of-type(3) {
  top: 60px;
}
.yourElem:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: 40px;
}
.yourElem:nth-of-type(1) {
  top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: This works beautifully. Love the use of deeper LESS functionality.

Comment: needs to be
    &:nth-of-type(@{index}) {
        top: @index * 20px;
    }

Comment: @Joram: Thanks for the alert on this. The original syntax was for pre 1.4 versions, so I've updated the answer for 1.4+ versions based on your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way that this is possible. Would be pretty cool, but I guess that's what javascript is for.

```
$('.parentDiv').children('div').each(function() {
    $(this).css({"top": num * 20 + "px"});
    num = num + 1;
});
```

Here's the full js solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/VbuQ9/

You can play around with the LESS fiddle here if you want.
http://jsfiddle.net/hV8sX/1/